# Кто-нибудь может помочь реализовать смену данных пользователя самим пользователем?

Tags: php, html

Есть 2 формы:

- для смены логина;
- для смены пароля.

Пароль в данном случае захеширован, через  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
Я всё пытаюсь и никак не могу сделать так, чтобы пароль захешированный изменялся. Обычный пароль меняется, а захешированный нет. Я не знаю, как это реализовать, может кто помочь? Вот код. Там много ошибок. Я в программировании новичок, так что, не ругайтесь.

Вот PHP код:

````
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

  session_start();

  $conn_db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practice");

  $fsmsg = "";

  $username = $_POST['username'];

  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];

  $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];

  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $new_username = $_POST['new_username'];

  $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);



  // Если кнопка апдейт нажата, изменить значения полей

  if (isset($_POST['update'])){

    $update2 = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$new_password' WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$old_password'";
    $resultupdate = mysqli_query($conn_db, $update2) or die (mysqli_error($conn_db));  
    
  }

  if (isset($_POST['update'])){

    $update = "UPDATE `users` SET `username`='$new_username' WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='$password'";
    $resultupdate = mysqli_query($conn_db, $update) or die (mysqli_error($conn_db));

  }```

Вот код формы:

```<div class="container-fluid padding">
        <div class="row padding">
          <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5">
    
          <br>

      <form action="red.php" method="POST" style="display: block; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; background: #f2f1f0; padding: 20px; color:#555; text-align: center;">

        <h3>Форма для смены пароля</h3>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputlogin"><h3>Введите имя пользователя</h3></label>
          <input type="login" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputlogin2" aria-describedby="loginHelp" required placeholder="Введите имя пользователя" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Используйте только цифры и латинские буквы">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputpassword"><h3>Старый пароль</h3></label>
          <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputpassword" aria-describedby="passwordHelp" required placeholder="Введите старый пароль" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Используйте только цифры и латинские буквы">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword2"><h3>Новый пароль</h3></label>
          <input type="password" name="new_password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" aria-describedby="passwordHelp" required placeholder="Введите новый пароль" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Используйте только цифры и латинские буквы">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="id" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck3" required>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck3"><h5>Подтвердить изменение</h5></label>
        </div>
        
        <form method="POST">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="update">Изменить</button>
        </form>


      </form>

          </div>
          
            <div class="col-lg-5">

            <br>

            <form action="red.php" method="POST" style="display: block; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; background: #f2f1f0; padding: 20px; color:#555; text-align: center;">

              <h3>Форма для смены логина</h3>
              <br>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputemail"><h3>Введите Email</h3></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-@-.]+" placeholder="Введите свой Email">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputpassword"><h3>Введите пароль</h3></label>
               <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputpassword" aria-describedby="passwordHelp" required placeholder="Введите пароль" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Используйте только цифры и латинские буквы">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputlogin"><h3>Новый логин</h3></label>
                <input type="login" name="new_username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputlogin" aria-describedby="loginHelp" required placeholder="Введите новый логин" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Используйте только цифры и латинские буквы">
              </div>

              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="id" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck3" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck3"><h5>Подтвердить изменение</h5></label>
              </div>
          
              <form method="POST">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="update">Изменить</button>
              </form>

      </form>
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <form class="text-center text-danger">

        <?php

          if(!empty($fsmsg)) echo("<br><h2>{$fsmsg}</h2>\n");

        ?>

      </form>```
````

Comment: $_POST['password'] тоже должен отличаться $_POST['new_password']

Comment: Вы хотите просто реализовать возможность смены пароля любого пользователя (которого вводим)? Если да - нет смысла сессию использовать. Если нет - в сессии нужно хранить текущего пользователя и ему менять пароль, никакой ввод логина не нужен

Comment: @Jean-Claude, Да. Спасибо, изменил. Что следует сделать дальше?

Comment: @InDevX Да. Любого, что введёт пользователь. Ведь априори пользователь не знает, имена других пользователей или их пароли. Сам, к сожалению по времени не успеваю этому обучиться, поэтому решил обратиться к профессионалам

Comment: @InDevX Да и, естественно, чтобы пароль хешировался, при изменении пароля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте у Вас скорее всего ошибка в SQL Запросе (AND `password`='$old_password'";)
Так как функция password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
Будет воpвращать на один и тот же пароль всегда разный hash
Вам нужно верифицировать hash в БД что-то типа:

```
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
       if (isHashVerify($username, $old_password, $conn_db)) {
          $newHash = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $update2 = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$newHash' WHERE 
                                                `username`='$username'";
          $resultupdate = mysqli_query($conn_db, $update2) or die 
          (mysqli_error($conn_db));
          $fsmsg = $new_password;
       } else {
           $fsmsg = 'Старый пароль не подходит!';
       }

    }

function isHashVerify($username, $oldPassword, $db)
{
    $query = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE  `username`='$username'";
    $currentPassword = mysqli_query($db, $query)->fetch_assoc() 
                                                or die (mysqli_error($db));
    return password_verify($oldPassword, $currentPassword["password"]);
}
```

Comment: А есть вариант вывод echo на другой строке? Нашёл такой вариант. Но при этом ошибку выводит всегда
<?php

          if(!empty($fsmsg)) echo("<br><h2>{$fsmsg}</h2>\n");

        ?>

Comment: Вы это про сообщения о том, что новый пароль или старый пароль не подходит?
Вам нужно в if'е писать $fsmsg =  $new_password; а в else  $fsmsg =  'Старый пароль не подходит!'; пример "кода" я поправил...

Comment: Да. Но мне нужно, чтобы это было не сверху страницы, а после форм. Вот я пытаюсь сейчас реализовать таким образом: <?php if(!empty($fsmsg)) echo("<br><h2>{$fsmsg}</h2>\n"); ?>
Но у меня это сообщение весит постоянно. Даже без изменения пароля. Просто, как заголовок

Comment: "Весит" какой текст - то? типа после F5 или что или когда открываете страницу сразу "весит" если после обновления страницы отображается: Старый пароль не подходит! это из-за post запроса Вам нужно сделать редирект или написать нормальную форму php + javascript :)

Comment: Текст на странице весит всегда. Это будто просто Label. Когда захожу на страницу и когда обновляю, вот. Этот код делал не я. Я его где-то подсмотрел вроде и пытался модернизировать, но ничего не получилось, ибо глупый ещё в этом. Поэтому обратился сюда. Я пытался закинуть ту функцию и условие вниз под формой, оно работает. Так работает, только почему-то нельзя листануть страницу вниз, т.е ниже PHP кода. Страница будто заканчивается на тех двух формах, хотя там есть ещё секция с изображением и футером)

Comment: Я надеюсь, что Вы эту форму не используете у себя на “боевом” сайте онлайн так как она может быть подвержена sql инъекции... у Вас есть телега или почта? Тут не особо удобно переписку вести Вам по хорошему нужно переписать это форму

Comment: Конечно нет. Это на локалке будет. Для дипломного проекта осталось доделать пару моментов. Можно списаться в телеге: @shaderdsher. Или можете написать свою. Я вам напишу)